# Is there a geometric way to understand the group law on an elliptic curve over a finite field?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

For elliptic curves over $\mathbb{R}$ or (some over)$\mathbb{C}$ or even $\mathbb{Q}$(for $\mathbb{Q}$, one can act like the points are not discrete and imitate the method for $\mathbb{R}$), one could use the chord tangent method to add two points on curve. However, for elliptic curves over finite fields, there's no apparent 'curve' like structure and it doesn't seem like the chord tangent method can be used there to add points. I can't find a pattern for how points are added. [[image: It's the plot of the curve <span class=]$x^3+x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{13}$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vaTO.png)

Comment: You are drawing the solutions as integers rather than in $F_{13}$ (of course your piece of paper is not suitable to draw in that space). In order to draw those dots, you made a choice about how to put $x \in F_{13}$ as an integer. Namely the choice to put in $[0,12]$.

Comment: You can still draw a(n imaginary) line between two points in your diagram. Only it will "loop around" when it reaches the edge and only actually consist of the points where the imaginary line intersects grid points.

Comment: I made it on [cryptography.se], [Graphically representing points on Elliptic Curve over finite field](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87545/18298) including addition and torus. Does that helpful? Drawing the lines is time-consuming...